# access local web server php page in online hosted php page

Tags: php

i want to get response from local web-server in php, to acheive this i have installed xamp and provide permission to "allow from all" in xamp config file, then i have forwarded the port in my router, now when access my php page by url "   [my dynamic ip]:port/test.php  " from other network or using proxy then i successfully get the response, but when i try to access this page in php then server doesn't give any response.

> No data received
>
> "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Here are
>   some suggestions: Reload this webpage later. Error 324
>   (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without
>   sending any data."

php code for accessing the url is

```
<?php
   $url = 'http://[my dynamic Ip]:10081/test.php';
   $handle = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
   $response = curl_exec($handle);
   echo $response;
   curl_close($handle);
?>
```

kindly solve my problem please..

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs?  How about if you replace your dynamic IP with something like "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" for the loopback interface?

Answer (score 0):

You access you web server from PC by providing local IP address which is 127.0.0.1 or localhost and not the public one.

PS: Never hard-code the URL, instead try to generate it.

```
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ":10081" . "/test.php";
```

You cannot call your own phone can you? That's the same with IP addresses.

Comment: actually the scenario is that , i have hosted a php script on 000webhost, and want to get html response from local webserver in the php script.